# Querying a tree structure with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an old database that I'm converting from using pure SQL queries to using Entity Framework Core instead. Most of the work is already done, but I'm having problems with a recursive tree structure.

Here's my (simplified) table structure:

```
ProductCategory
    Id
    CategoryChidrenKey
    Name

CategoryChildren
    Id
    Key
    ChildCategoryId
```

So the relations are

```
CategoryChildrenKey --> Key      ChildCategoryId --> Id
ProductCategory (1) --> (1) CategoryChildren (1) --> (*) ProductCategory.
```

I have no Idea why the structure has been defined this way, but I will have to work with it. At the moment I'm still using pure SQL for fetching tree data.

How could I model and query this structure with EF Core? And how could I limit recursion depth if I only want to retrieve parent or children (1 level up or down)? I would prefer to not model `CategoryChildren` table at all, but instead have a direct reference to parent and children.

I need to perform at least following queries:

1. Get parent category for a category.
2. Get full category path for a category, e.g. "Root - Parent1 - Parent2 - Category"
3. Get all direct child categories for a category.
4. Get the full category structure starting from root.

It would help if even some of these could be implemented using EF Core, e.g. 1 and 3.

EDIT: It would also be useful if I could manually join some extra data, something like

```
SELECT category.Id as ParentId
FROM CategoryChildren
JOIN ProductCategory on ProductCategory.CategoryChildrenKey = CategoryChildren.Key
WHERE CategoryChildren.ChildCategoryId = <category id>
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I would like to see the DDL of creating tables.

Comment: CTE is used in SQL to work with recursive queries. But EF does not have the means to work with CTE in LINQ. Only use raw SQL queries. Or use an additional library for this purpose.

Comment: Among the several ways to store hierarchies in relational databases, I know only one that uses two tables, it is called Bridge Table/Closure Table. But it doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.